# Understanding formation of Request Headers

Tags: reactjs, webpack, http-headers, next.js, gzip

I am running a [NextJS](https://nextjs.org/) application, and I observed that `JavaScript` resources are not getting `gzipped` on mobile (on desktop it works fine). On further debugging, I found that this is because the Request Headers in mobile are not sending the [Accept-Encoding](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept-Encoding) header. These JS files are basically chunks (bundles of JS code) downloaded using a `<script>` tag. Now I understand that there is no way to add Request Headers to a `<script>` tag, but I can see that the `Accept-Encoding` headers are present when running the app in desktop resolution.

So I want to understand where are these Request Headers (specifically `Accept-Encoding`) added to outgoing JavaScript file requests? Is it automatically added by the browser when making a request, or added by `NextJS`, or `WebPack` (embedding it when sending the html page for the first time to client)? And how can I fix this issue? Note that I observe this behaviour even on my local machine running on `localhost:3000`.

Answer (score 0):

That header is set by the `client` and it is used to tell the server what kind of content encoding ( compressions algorithm ) it can understand, so basically the client will get the gzipped files if it declares that it can accept them, and the server is able to serve them (nextjs has gzip compression `on` by default).

[Mdn Docs Accept-Encoding](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept-Encoding)

[Next.js Docs gzip](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/compression)

Comment: I haven't set `compress` to `false` in my `next.config.js`